# What is the distribution of the random sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $X_n$ be iid $\pm1$ with probability $1/2$. What is the distribution of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\log n}{n}X_n$?

I can conclude the sum converges almost surely since $\sum_n Var(\dfrac{\log n}{n}X_n)<\infty$. Then I tried with the characteristic function but I am getting an infinite product of $\cos(t\dfrac{\log n}{n})$ and I don't know what happens to this product.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite product
$$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty \cos\left(t \frac{\log n}{n}\right) $$
converges since $$\cos\left(t \frac{\log n}{n}\right) \approx 1 - \frac{t^2 \log^2 n}{2 n^2}$$ and $\sum_{n} 1/n^2$ converges.  But I don't expect there to be a closed form of this product.

Comment: That the infinite product converges is clear from the fact that the random sum converges almost surely and hence in distribution, so characteristic functions must converge. I need the form of the limit.

Comment: What makes you think it has a "form"?

Comment: This is an exam question. At least can we say that the convergence does not happen to a Normal?

Comment: It can't be normal because the characteristic function is $0$ at $\pi n/(2 \log n)$ for $n \ge 2$.